# Convert my model predicted array to categorical using a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras, pytorch

I've built a MLP neural network -> Trained -> Saved -> loaded -> now I'm testing my loaded model.

I've used `y_pred=loaded_model(Variable(featuresTest))` to predict using pytorch then converted my tensor to array `y_pred_arr` and here's my result:

```py
array([[-1.1663326 ,  0.369073  ],
       [-1.4255922 ,  0.23584184],
       [-2.045612  ,  1.4165274 ],
       ...,
       [ 4.327711  , -4.1331964 ],
       [-1.255816  ,  0.65834284],
       [ 6.642277  , -7.4430957 ]], dtype=float32)
```

My true labels array `y_test` which I'm trying to compare to are categorical

```
array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       ...,
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

now I'm trying to use `sklearn.metrics` ->classification report however as my predicted array is obviously continuous I'm trying to convert it to a categorical which uses a condition converting the highest positive number in each of the array to a `1` for instance:

my first set in the predicted array is  `[-1.4255922 ,  0.23584184],` <- this would be converted to `[ 0 , 1]` as `0.2358` is the highest positive class in the prediction.

I've tried to use:

```
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
labels123 = to_categorical(y_pred_arr, dtype = "int64")
```

however, got this error:

```
IndexError: index -75 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 74
```

Could I please get some assistance with this. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
labels123 = to_categorical(np.argmax(y_pred_arr, 1), dtype = "int64")
```

Comment: Kindly click on the check mark beside my answer to accept it as the answer. You can also upvote it if you found it useful.